# How to get back-office root url fromt the front-controller in prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am looking for generating admin root url( like: http://localhost/prestashop174/admin084oazcuj/index.php ) from a front-office controller in prestashop 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can get link of admin in front controller by using Link class

```
$this->context->link->getAdminBaseLink() . basename(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your hard working.But it's not working in my side. the const PS_ADMIN_DIR is not definded. Even the method "getAdminBaseLink" is not defined in link class. did you made them manually?

Comment: You are using 1.7.8?

Comment: Can you share me exact version then i can help you

Comment: i am using 1.7.4.2

Comment: Ok I looked my answer underscores at beginning and end was trimmed as I was not write it as code

Answer (score 1):

Try `_PS_ADMIN_DIR_` instead of `PS_ADMIN_DIR` , because of the PS_ADMIN_DIR is not defined by PrestaShop, and could be undefined

```
if (!$link) {
            $link = Context::getContext()->link;
        }    
$link->getAdminBaseLink() . basename(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_)
```

or

```
$this->context->link->getAdminBaseLink() . basename(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_)
```